# Is there any way to fix node js bug and without re-installing windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed node js many times and re-installed it, cleared cache and tried everything to make it work, but I can't use it to compile pug and scss files in my project. At first I installed node_modules without any problems, but 'npm start' command to start compiling the files won't work. Many people from my team use it without any problems but somehow when I followed the same orders and installed everything correctly, I have this kind of errors. Can anyone help me fix this? I'm using same codes of node js of terminal for 3rd days and literally tried every way I found in google. (including using yarn, reinstalling nodejs, some npm codes to clear cache, force install and etc).

[errors after using npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA3dm.png)

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (grunt) => {



grunt.initConfig({

        sass : {
            options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                sourceMap: false
            },
            dist : {
                files: {
                    'dist/assets/css/main.css' : 'src/styles/template.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        pug : {
            compile : {
                files: {
                    'dist/index.html': ['src/template/index.pug']
                }
            }
        },

        prettify: {
            options: {
                "indent": 2,
                "indent_char": " ",
                "indent_scripts": "normal",
                "wrap_line_length": 0,
                "brace_style": "collapse",
                "preserve_newlines": true,
                "max_preserve_newlines": 1,
                "unformatted": [
                    "a",
                    "code",
                    "pre"
                ]
            },
            files: {
                src: 'dist/index.html',
                dest: 'dist/index.html'
            }
        },

        watch : {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            css : {
                files: ['src/styles/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            html : {
                files : ['src/template/**/*.pug'],
                tasks : ['pug', 'prettify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        },

        express : {
            all : {
                options : {
                    port : 1994,
                    hostname : 'localhost',
                    bases : ['./dist/'],
                    livereload : true
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-pug');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-prettify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express');


    grunt.registerTask('server', ['express', 'watch']);

}
```

and also custom script

```
{
  "name": "random name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Random name",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run open",
    "langbuilder": "node langbuilder",
    "projectbuilder": "node projectbuilder",
    "cronbuilder": "node cronbuilder",
    "configbuilder": "node configbuilder",
    "open": "concurrently \"grunt server\"  \"open http://localhost:1994\""
  }

 
}
```

full log of errors

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'open'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.6.3
2 info using node@v15.12.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\z.metreveli\Desktop\new123\promostarterpack\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\z.metreveli\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\z.metreveli\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
19 verbose npm-session 7c4573983650cce7
20 timing npm:load Completed in 17ms
21 timing command:run Completed in 860ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
23 verbose pkgid promostarterpack@1.0.0
24 verbose cwd C:\Users\z.metreveli\Desktop\new123\promostarterpack
25 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
26 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "open"
27 verbose node v15.12.0
28 verbose npm  v7.6.3
29 error code 1
30 error path C:\Users\z.metreveli\Desktop\new123\promostarterpack
31 error command failed
32 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c concurrently "grunt server"  "open http://localhost:1994"
33 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: Please check the error, its says your 'open' custom script and grunt both run in parallel add both the scripts in the project.

Comment: It might be that `open` is a macOS-specific command and doesn't exist on Windows.

Comment: One of your errors is due to a typo: rather than `os.tmpDir()`, use `os.tmpdir()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on there, including what looks like a missing `scripts` entry for `open` in `package.json` (first error).

Second error in your log is a typo: rather than `os.tmpDir()`, use [`os.tmpdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir).

Personally, I would not use Grunt these days, but something like Rollup or Webpack. GitHub has a [PUG/SCSS boilerplate for Webpack](https://github.com/alexnoz/webpack-pug-scss-boilerplate).

Comment: I edited the package.json file and removed unnecessary codes like Dependencies, author, etc..

Comment: Looks like you may have removed the entry `scripts`? Or at least the `open` field of `scripts`. It's been years since I used grunt. But you certainly have a typo unless your `os` is not the standard, built-in Node package.

Comment: I removed them here, in my package.json I have these scripts plus dependencies urls and etc, but this is the only script and for others it works well.. something is wrong with my node.js and don't know what, windows can't simply read it while others can..

Comment: Looks like Node itself is fine, but you certainly have at least a typo

Comment: I can't find that os.tmpDir() code as I googled it's standart node js file but how can I edit it?

Comment: If you post in your question the errors from the full log, perhaps someone can help? You can see the path to the full log in the error message.